# How can I Filter array with nested subscribes in Angular?

Tags: angular

I fetch from server some users  for each user I want to check if he has some permissions, if he does not has I want to remove him from the list.

I cant find good solution, and I tried this example but its does not work. I am sure that there is better and shorter solution, and I will glad for some help.

```
createPermittedUsers() {
        this.userApi.findlAllUsers().pipe(
            map(users=> users.filter(user => {
                    this.permissionsApi.findPermissionByUserId(user.id).subscribe(
                        (permission:boolean) => {
                            return permission;
                        }
                    );
                })
            ),
            map( // remove the current user from list
                users =>
                   users.filter(user => user.id !== this.currentUser.id))
        )
            .subscribe((filteredUsers) => {
                this.filteredUsers = filteredUsers;
            });
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good way to do it suppose there are 100 users then there are going to be 100 permission api calls...

Comment: is the userApi and permissionsApi something you control? if so, then you should create a new function on the server that filters all the permissions for you. Doing this is going to use a a lot of bandwidth and you could potentially DDOS yourself. Also, you can't use the `filter()` in the first map with an observable.